# Several questions about state space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Here are several questions about the state space of a C*-algebra $A$:

1. Let $A$ be a unital and separable C*-algebra, can we find a faithful state $\phi \in S(A)$. ( The $S(A)$ denotes the state space of $A$)
2. It is not hard to verify that: if C*-algebra $A$ is unital, then $S(A)$ is weak-* closed convex set. What about the case that $A$ is non-unital?
3. Let $A$ be unital C*-algebra and $h\in A$ be any self-adjoint element. Let $C^{*}(h,~1_{A})$ be the unital C*-algebra generated by $h$ and $1_{A}$. Can we find a pure state $\psi\in P(C)$ such that $|\psi(h)|=||h||$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Deduce that there is countable set $\{q_n\}$ dense in the unit ball.  Let $r_n=q_n^*q_n$. Given any $a\in A^+_1$, there exists $b\in A$ with $b^*b=a$. Given $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $q_n$ with $\|q_n-b\|<\varepsilon/2$. Then
   $$
   \|r_n-a\|=\|q_n^*q_n-b^*b\|\leq\|q_n^*(q_n-b)\|+\|(q_n^*-b^*)b\|\leq2\|q_n-b\|<\varepsilon.
   $$
   So the sequence $\{r_n\}$ is dense in $A^+_1$.

For each $n$, let $\varphi_n\in S(A)$ with $\varphi_n(r_n)=\|r_n\|$.Then define the state $\phi$ by
$$
\phi(a)=\sum_n\frac{\varphi_n(a)}{2^n}.
$$
If $a\in A^+_1$ and $a\ne0$, then there exists $r_n$ with $\|a-r_n\|<\|a\|/4$. Then $\|r_n\|\geq3\|a\|/4$, and
$$
\varphi_n(a)=|\varphi_n(a-r_n)+\varphi_n(r_n)|=|\varphi_n(a-r_n)+\|r_n\|\,|
\geq\|r_n\|-|\varphi_n(a-r_n)|\\
\geq3\|a\|/4-|\varphi_n(a-r_n)|>3\|a\|/4-\|a\|/4=\|a\|/2.
$$
Then $\phi(a)>0$, and so $\phi$ is faithful.

2. When $A$ is not unital and $\tilde A$ is the unitization of $A$,  $S(\tilde A)\cup\{\hat 1\}$, where $\hat 1$ is the state $\hat 1(a,\lambda)=\lambda$. While convex, $A(A)$ is not weak$^*$-closed.
3. Yes, that can be done in any C$^*$-algebra.

Comment: Thanks, Martin. But I still have some questions on your answer: 1. In the four lines of your answer, why $||q_{n}^{*}(q_{n}-b)||+||(q_{n}^{*}-b^{*})b||\leq 2||q_{n}-b||$? 2. If we take any $a\in A_{1}^{+}$, then $\phi(a)>0$. This implies $\phi$ is faithful? 3. Is this method a standard method in C*-algebra or is this a known result?

Comment: 1. You add and subtract $q_n^*b$, you use the triangle inequality and that all elements are in the unit ball. 2. Of course: faithfulness is $(\phi(a)=0\implies a=0)$; the contrapositive is $(a\ne0\implies\phi(a)>0)$. 3. Yes, is it a basic result about C$^*$-algebras.

Comment: Yes, I got the point. However, could you recommend me some books which contain this result(the question 1)? I still hope to see some relevant propositions.

Comment: I did a quick search and I couldn't find it (I tried Kadison, Davidson, Blackadar, Murphy). Not saying that it's not in one (or all?) of them, but I got nowhere.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Isn't there one extra state on $\tilde{A}$, the state $\hat{1}$ taking $a + \lambda 1_{\tilde{A}}\mapsto \lambda$? In that case $S(\tilde{A}) = S(A)\cup\{\hat{1}\}$.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. I have no idea why I wrote that.